# cannot convert from android.app.FragmentManager to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-fragments

I am creating an app using Fragments for tablet.I have so far created some buttons on the left side and the fragments appear on clicking the buttons.

But i am experiencing error in my MainActivity.java file "Type mismatch error:cannot convert from `android.app.FragmentManager` to `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`" And that is the main reason that i cannot implement it.I have already imported `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`.

How can i resolve my problem?

My code for MainActivity.java

```
      import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Fragment fragment;
    Button btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        btn6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn6);

        FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();

        StartFragment myfragment=new StartFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.myfragment,myfragment);
        ft.commit();
        btn4.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
        btn5.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
        btn6.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
    }



        Button.OnClickListener btnOnClickListener=new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Fragment newfragment;
                if(v==btn1)
                {
                    newfragment=new Fragment1();
                }
                else if(v==btn2)
                {
                    newfragment=new Fragment2();
                }
                else if(v==btn3)
                {
                    newfragment=new Fragment3();
                }
                else if(v==btn4)
                {
                    newfragment=new Fragment4();
                }
                else if(v==btn5)
                {
                    newfragment=new Fragment5();
                }
                else if(v==btn6)
                {
                    newfragment=new Fragment6();
                }
                else 
                {
                    newfragment=new StartFragment();
                }
                FragmentTransaction transaction=getFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.myfragment,newfragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                transaction.commit();
            }
        };
        }
```

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` in your code, not `getFragmentManager()` - see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()) for more details.

You also need to extend your class from `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`, not just from standard `android.Activity` to get this method.

Comment: yes you can use what David has suggested.it worked in my case.

Comment: Thanks David for your kind help.It worked and now i am furthur working on it.

Comment: Worth noting that you can extend `ActionBarActivity` from your `Activity` now too.

Comment: If my class extends Fragment and i am using a FragmentPagerAdapter then what should i do?